# Geofencing not working when phone screen is locked

Tags: android, gps, google-play-services, intentservice, geofencing

My application uses geofencing, it shows notifications when the phone enters certain areas (geofences). Code works perfectly fine when phone is unlocked, however if the phone is locked the geofence trigger doesn't work after a couple of minutes.
I've figured out a workaround, opening google maps and starting a navigation session seems to keep the GPS data flowing without issues(even if the phone is locked). I'm wondering if there is a way to achieve this without having a google maps navigation session open.

NOTE: Battery drain is not an issue, so if there is some way to fetch GPS coordinates continuously please let me know. Also, I tested the app out by spoofing the phones GPS, it works just fine.

Code for adding the geofence:

```
geofences.add(new Geofence.Builder()
            .setRequestId("YOU ARE HOME!")
            .setCircularRegion(13.990979,90.294995,60)
            .setTransitionTypes(Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_ENTER)
            .setExpirationDuration(Geofence.NEVER_EXPIRE)
            .build()
    );
```

Comment: Are you using the geofencing function from the Play Services location API (see https://developer.android.com/training/location/geofencing.html)?  If so, can you post the code where you set up the GeofencingRequest?

Comment: @ScottKronheim I've posted the code.

Comment: you testing this on Android o?

Comment: @AmeerHamza Nougat.